# Несколько AND в MYSQL запросе

Tags: sql

```
WHERE `type` = 1 AND `type` = 2 AND `type` = 3 AND `type` = 4
```

Почему же так нельзя? Есть обход? IN не предлагать!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Поле не может быть равно 4-м разным значениям одновременно. Используйте `OR`

```
WHERE `type` = 1 OR `type` = 2 OR `type` = 3 OR `type` = 4
```

Comment: @KaZaца, я Вас опередил, но так как варианты схожи, помечаю Ваш ответ как правильный)

Answer (score 1):

а может все тaки :

```
WHERE `type` >= 1 AND `type` <= 4
```

Comment: А если нужно будет только 1,3,4 - не выход в случае автоматической генерации запроса)