# SQL-запрос на вывод двух значений полей

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, запрос SELECT, чтобы на выходе было **два** поля **(alias)** с результатами:

```
SELECT ID from Table WHERE (UsersAlbumsType = 0 AND  UsersAlbumsDefault = 1) AND (UsersAlbumsType = 1 AND UsersAlbumsDefault = 1)
```

Для двух условий **AND** - разное значение ID.

Будет ли такое решение считаться приемлемым?

```
SELECT A.UsersAlbumsId as A1, B.UsersAlbumsId as B2 FROM usersalbums A, usersalbums B WHERE (A.UsersAlbumsType = 1 AND A.UsersAlbumsDefault = 1) AND (B.UsersAlbumsDefault = 1 AND B.UsersAlbumsType);
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Несколько AND в MYSQL запросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/186558/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-and-%d0%b2-mysql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT ID from Table WHERE (UsersAlbumsType = 0 OR UsersAlbumsType = 1) AND UsersAlbumsDefault = 1

Comment: Неплохо сократили) Но мне нужно для каждого из **UsersAlbumsType** иметь свой ID. Т. е. в Вашем примере на выходе я смогу получить **N** значений ID. Только вот какой из них к какому **UsersAlbumsType** относится - уже не определить. Я расширил вопрос и привел свое решение с применение альясов. Насколько оно будет корректно?

Comment: SELECT ID, UserAlbumsType WHERE (UsersAlbumsType = 0 OR UsersAlbumsType = 1) AND UsersAlbumsDefault = 1

Теперь для каждого ID рядом будет выводиться UserAlbumsType.

Зачем вам усложнять запрос вводом alias?

Comment: Для того чтобы в PHP не делать лишних проверок, а применить только возвращенный ID.