# SQL запрос для фильтра товаров

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть 3 таблицы: Товары, атрибуты, значения
id атрибутов известны
Нужно вывести товары по определённым параметрам атрибутов

```
$sql = "SELECT g.id, g.title
        FROM goods g
        LEFT JOIN attr_values attr_v ON g.id = attr_v.id_goods
        WHERE 
        (
          ((attr_v.id_attr, attr_v.value) = (1, 'параметр...'))
        AND
          ((attr_v.id_attr, attr_v.value) = (2, 'параметр...'))
        )
";
```

В результате получаю пустой результат=((
В чём проблема и как можно переписать запрос, предпочтительно для работы с большим количеством информации
Заранее спасибо

Comment: `AND` - это `И`, как может аттрибут иметь `id` равным и 1, и 2? Надо `OR` использовать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Несколько AND в MYSQL запросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/186558/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-and-%d0%b2-mysql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5)

Comment: Вы наверное не поняли смысла всей задачи, если поставить логику OR .то я согласен все будет работать но при этом запрос будет возвращать не верные данные. Если ставим OR то результат будет отдавать товары в которых есть например пераый параметр но нет второго

Comment: Да, был не прав. Это дубликат другого [вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/354353)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выборка записей, одновременно имеющих несколько значений](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/354353/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)